# django admin keeps raising Validation Error when using separate forms for adding and updating

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I have two forms : one for adding and the other for updating

```
class UserAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = []
    email = forms.CharField()
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False), required=True, label='Mot de passe')
    is_teacher = forms.TypedChoiceField(coerce=lambda x: x == 'True', choices=((True, 'OUI'), (False, 'NON')), widget=forms.RadioSelect, label='Enseignant ?')


class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = []
    email = forms.CharField()
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False), required=False, label='Mot de passe')
    is_teacher = forms.TypedChoiceField(coerce=lambda x: x == 'True', choices=((True, 'OUI'), (False, 'NON')), widget=forms.RadioSelect, label='Enseignant ?')
```

This is the `ModelAdmin`

```
class UserAdmin(UserUploadAdmin):
    fields = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password', 'is_teacher']
    form = UserChangeForm
    
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):            
        if not obj:
            return UserAddForm
        return super(UserAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

The idea is to handle the case of empty password. If it's a new user then the password is required and if I'm updating then it will be empty and therefore ignored.

The problem is that the add form keeps raising validation errors, even when the fields are not empty

[image]

The update form however works fine without any problems.

Comment: Why did you put `fields = []` in the `Meta` ?

Comment: It's required by Django. Perhaps this is the issue ?

Comment: `fields` is required, but, I wounder why the ***empty list***

Comment: It worked after I typed all the fields. Is there any way to mention all of them using a shortcut like * ?

Comment: There is a shortcut `__all__` for this. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use